# Using AngularJS routing with a single-page web app

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, angularjs-routing

I read about angularJS [routing](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07). I want to implement it in my web app, but unfortunately I have a rather difficult situation changing to routing now I think. This is how my app works now (and I know it's probably not the way it should, but it does work):

I have one controller for the whole app. 
The view is built with some divs, one of which is a menu div. The others are 'partial' views as angularjs calls them I guess. But the problem I see here is that two of my partial views can be shown at the same time (page is built like this, partial view only takes a portion of the page for itself).

So what I am doing is: I click the button on the menu -> one partial view shows up (ng-show), then I can click something on this partial view to get the second partial view opened on the same page (menu and first partial must stay the way they are).

At the moment I include partials within some divs with php include (which is I am sure the wrong way) and the divs have ng-show on them so that nothing is shown on the beginning. Then I manipulate all the clicks in the menu with setting ng-show parameters of all my partials (views). So if one button is clicked I hide all the others (with ng-click and a function inside controller). But this is tedious work and not the angularJS way and that is why I am asking this question here.

Example of my included partial (stripped of all unnecessary css classes etc):

```
<div ng-show="showNames">
    <?php include_once("views/AREA1/names.php") ?>  
</div>
```

And names.php has for instance just some few  elements with ng-repeat and other angularJS directives… I have many includes like that and they work with just ng-show manipulation very well. But now that I grasped some of the AngularJS concepts I see that I made a mistake…

**To sum up:** how can I use angularJS routes (with ng-view perhaps?-not necessary) to show views within my web app? (taking into account the situation that I have described above). I just want user to be able to know on what "part of page" he is at any given moment.

**EDIT**: I went trough [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/) and I reckon I could work it out: I need a structure similar to the one in this example *2.1 Online Demo*, but furthermore I need to be able to click something on ng-view which should open another view (first one should stay in place). Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

By using `routing` feature in `AngularJS`, the html content of `ng-view` will be totally replaced by the new partial. You should not use `ng-view` for such a purpose like showing multiple partials at the same time.

But you can think about mix the `ng-view` and `ng-include`.

Let's say, we click each item on the menu, `ng-view` changes the sub-partial, you can have `ng-include` in your sub-partials which we can all it here like sub-sub-partial.

Try reading [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude)

Comment: hm tried ng-include but it creates new $scope and thus makes more problems than it solves it seems?

Comment: Sorry, it might be late to answer you. Here is a demo `Plunker` from me, show you the way using `ng-include` to bring sub-page in, http://plnkr.co/edit/bvr6764VR3Iq8AUO1Urh?p=info

Comment: And yes, `ng-include` would create new `scope`. What problem were you encountering? Better to give a `plunker`. Then we could solve the issue based on real case.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has `ng-view` which would contain the main theme of current context, rest of the UI elements are all managed by `ng-include`. Routes also work in sync with `nv-view`.

If your view requirement are complex look at [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) component that supports various combinations.

Comment: Hmm, that looks rather complex. Ng-include creates new $scope and that bothers me a bit. I still don't know how to start implementing routing into my app

Comment: Inside your partial that is rendered in `ng-view`, you can always add section which is hidden by default and based on the click, is shown. You can use ng-if or ng-show\hide to do this.

Comment: But then I don't have custom url for these clicked sub-pages which I would like to if I am going to have routing. At the moment I have ng-show/hide to manipulate the whole page, which works just fine - the only thing is I can't get to certain page with url but only by clicking to get there

Comment: Yes and that is why i asked you to look into `ui-router`. One another think i can suggest is to use querystring with the route for sub views. In this case you can set `reloadOnSearch` in the $routeProvider route collection to `false`. What would happen then is that the main view would not be swapped out, and you get the extra parameters from the url.

Comment: I wouldn't like to use ui-router since it is supposed to be in a heavy development phase and not for production use(unfortunately)… in any case I see I have rather difficult situation here ehh. thanks for your answers I will try to do some more research